# Unable to load /nowjs/now.js

Tags: node.js, nowjs-sockets

When I start the server, I get the following error

```
[Error: Unable to load shared library /home/boopathi/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-    proxy/lib/node-proxy.node]
Error: Unable to load shared library /home/boopathi/node_modules/now/node_modules/node-proxy/lib/node-proxy.node
at Object..node (module.js:465:11)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
at Module.require (module.js:359:17)
at require (module.js:370:17)
at Object.<anonymous> (/home/boopathi/node_modules/now/lib/proxy.js:10:13)
at Module._compile (module.js:434:26)
at Object..js (module.js:452:10)
at Module.load (module.js:353:31)
at Function._load (module.js:310:12)
```

When I make the node-proxy module manually, I get the following warning..

```
[2/2] cxx_link: build/Release/node-proxy_1.o -> build/Release/node-proxy.node
```

in yellow color...

Now I'm not able to load the /nowjs/now.js file

I tried --harmony_proxies .. but it did not help ..

Comment: What is your nodejs version? Run `node -v` to find it out.

Comment: 0.6.6... using Arch linux ... installed node using pacman

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should help you find it out:

Fire up `gdb node`. Type [`break node.cc:1624`](https://github.com/joyent/node/blob/v0.6.6/src/node.cc#L1624), then type `run yourscript.js`. When gdb hits the breakpoint, use `p/a dlerror()` to obtain the address of the error. It should print something like `$123 = 0xabcddefg`. Now use `x/s 0xabcddefg` (insert the address you got from the last command) to see the error. Is the error helpful?

Answer (score 0):

I encountered same problem with bcrypt and found it's because my node was 32bit and bcrypt was build as 64bit. After I build a 64bit node, all things work fine.

Answer (score 0):

I´ve tried this solution without success.

I guess the team made NowJS need to fix it current support in all plataforms. I cannot run NowJS under either Mac and Windows.

There is no way to accomplish it. Maybe some further version allow me to play with NowJS, but NOW, I can´t do it.